# Mahout: Why is using setProbes() having this affect?

Tags: classification, mahout

I'm using mahout 0.7 to do some classification. I have an encoder for a continuous variable

```
ContinuousValueEncoder durationPlanEncoder = new ContinuousValueEncoder("duration_plan");
```

The feature associated with this encoder is a number of days and can range from about 6 to 16.

I'm using an OnlineLogisticRegression model and I use the encoder to train it:

```
durationPlanEncoder.addToVector(null, <duration_plan double val>, trainDataVector);
```

For simplicity (since i'm trying to understand this whole classification thing while also learning Mahout), i am using 2 variables: 1) a categorical variable with 6 categories -- one of which ("dev") always predicts the =1 category; and 2) this "duration_plan" variable.

What i expect to find is that, when i give the classifier test data that consists of the category "dev" and a "duration_plan" value, the accuracy of the classifier will increase as the "duration_plan" value i give it gets closer to its average value across the training data. This is not what i'm seeing, however. Instead, the accuracy of the classifier improves as the value of "duration_plan" goes to 0.0. However -- there are no training vectors with duration_plan=0.0!! Why would this be the case?

Then i modified my durationPlanEncoder as follows:

```
durationPlanEncoder.setProbes(2);
```

and the accuracy improved. It got even better when i made the number of probes 20, then 200. Why? What is setProbes() doing and is this an anomaly or is this actually how i should be doing it?

The final part of my question is to mention that, even after setting setProbes(20), changing the value of "duration_plan" in the test data has **no** effect on the accuracy of the classifier -- which I don't think is how it should be. If i give a value for duration_plan that doesn't even exist in any of the training data and thus is never correlated with the =1 class, i would expect the classifier to classify the test sample as =0. Right? Which makes me think i must be coding something just plain wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Mahout documentation is woefully sparse.

thanks.